# IIF function with multiple expressions and operations in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I need to write a formula for a SSRS report like this

> if stateid=37 AND stateid=38 then
>   phy_target_tot.value*90/100,financial_target_tot.value*10/100,    sum(phy_target_tot.value*90/100)    ,sum(financial_target_tot.value*10/100)
>   else 
>  phy_target_tot.value*60/100,
>   financial_target_tot.value*40/100, 
>   sum(phy_target_tot.value*60/100)  ,   sum(financial_target_tot.value*40/100)

I tried this:

```
=IIf(Parameters!stateid.Value=38 AND Parameters!stateid.Value=37 ,Fields!Achivement_Financial_Gen*90\100,Fields!Achivement_Financial_Gen*60\100)
```

In the Expression column report showing an `#Error`. I need a correct syntax to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression uses character \  instead of character /  for divination.

Also you should use the Value property for your fields

For the given expression the following should work

```
=IIf(Parameters!stateid.Value=38 AND Parameters!stateid.Value=37 ,Fields!Achivement_Financial_Gen*90/100,Fields!Achivement_Financial_Gen*60/100)
```